# Async Action-Creator not properly awaited when calling in TouchableOpacity's onPress

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm facing a problem that I can't seem to find the mistake I made. I basically have a simple redux-thunk action creator that has some axios calls in it. I connect my component to this action creator with `connect` and then call it in a async method which gets passed to a `TouchablyOpacity` onPress prop.

Simplified code:

**Action creator:**

```
export const createUploadEntry = (
    step,
    image,
    base64,
    width,
    height,
    submissionEntry
) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(createUploadEntryStart());

    try {
        const response = await axios.put(...);
        console.log("finished creating submission entry");
        dispatch(createUploadEntrySuccess(response.data));
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Component from "./component";
import { createUploadEntry } from "../../../../store/actions/trainings";

export default connect(
    null,
    { createUploadEntry }
)(Component);
```

**Component.js**

```
const Test = (props) => {
    const onPressed = async () => {
        console.log("start awaiting");
        await props.createUploadEntry(...);
        console.log("finished awaiting");
        props.navigateToNext();  
    }

    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressed}>...</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

The output that I then get in the console is:

- start awaiting
- finished awaiting
- finished creating submission entry

The action creator involves uploading images, so it takes a bit of time and the "finished awaiting" is called right after the "start awaiting".

I hope I've described my problem well enough, and thanks in advance for any help!

Cheers

Comment: `createUploadEntry` isn't async here, it returns a function that is async. Try returning `resp` after dispatching `createUploadEntrySuccess`.

Comment: @Clarity doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have your tried `TouchableHighlight` instead of `TouchableOpacity`? I know it doesn't seem to be related but `TouchableOpacity` has some very nasty bugs that can only be replicated under very specific environments, and yours might be affected by it.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu didn't think of that yet, I'm gonna try it and come back to you! Thanks for the input!

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu didn't seem to make a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was another middleware that screwed up redux-thunk.

Comment: I'm wondering why someone downvotes a legitimate question and (although it was just a stupid mistake) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
export const createUploadEntry = (
    step,
    image,
    base64,
    width,
    height,
    submissionEntry
) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(createUploadEntryStart());

    try {
        const response = await axios.put(...);
        console.log("finished creating submission entry");
        dispatch(createUploadEntrySuccess(response.data));
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

try this  `return response;`

Comment: once try the return statement  with the response from  action

Comment: This suggestion has already been discussed in the comments, and in my opinion it shouldn't make any difference if the function returns nothing which will result in a Promise<void> or returns something which will result in a Promise<any>, it's still a promise. So this doesn't fix my issue.